# Typescript - is there a type for "(event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void"?

Tags: typescript

I find I'm repeating the same type `(event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void` over and over again in just about every component that has a click event (all buttons in my case). It seems like there should be a simpler `ButtonClick` type or similar for something as common as this.

Does anything like this exist or should I just export my own global interface/type for this so I don't keep repeating myself? Something like:

```
export interface I_ButtonClick {
  (event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void;
}
```

or

```
export type T_ButtonClick = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
```

Comment: I don't see a problem for creating your own type for this. That I know of, there isn't a type for this, but it would be cool if you found one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your previous post, you're using React in which case yes. React has a type called `MouseEventHandler` which usage looks like this.

```ts
const handleOnClick: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = (e) => // do something with e.
```